# Proving that ($x^2-xyz$) is rational when all three $x, y$ and $z$ are rational

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $x^2-xyz\,$ is rational when $x,y,z$ are all rational.

Should I prove this question by proving that multiplication or addition of rational numbers are rationals or there are better ways to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can go by definition as well: $x=a/b, y=c/d, \ldots$ and then show that this expression can also be written as a ratio of two integers (pretty much similar amount of work).

Comment: I'd say showing it with those closure properties is a slightly more elegant method, but both methods are perfectly serviceable

Comment: @Anurag A Hello and thanks for the suggestion. So, is getting to the results of ($a^2d$$f - c$e$b^2)/b^2$d$$f enough to prove this? By saying that the result is showing that the resulting number can be written as a division of two numbers?

Comment: @JOUA Yes, just make sure that the denominator is non-zero and it is division of two **integers**, not just any numbers. So in essence you are using the fact that product of two integers is an integers etc.. (also known as closure under multiplication...).

Comment: @Anurag A Isn't this going to cause a conflict when proving this? Because this becomes an exception?

Comment: @JOUA Not sure what do you mean by that. By **definition** if $x \in \Bbb{Q}$, then $x=a/b$ for some **integers** $a$ and $b$, where $b \neq 0$...

Comment: @Anurag A Exactly. I though this would have a proof without an exception because when I was proving another statement, my teacher told me that you shouldn't restrict it and you should make it possible with all numbers. It seems that this is the only answer! Thank you so much sir!

Comment: @Anurag A I wish you had added this as an answer so that I could accept your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the level and already known information. If you haven't proved yet that rational numbers are closed under multiplication and addition (so you cannot use it), you must begin from the definition of rational numbers:

Let $x=\dfrac ab$, $y=\dfrac cd$ and $z=\dfrac uv$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $u$ and $v$ are all integers, and $b$, $d$ and $v$ are not zero.

Proceed by evaluating the fraction and then show that the numerator and denominator are also going to be integers, and the denominator will be non-zero.

---

If you are allowed to use the closure of rational numbers under addition and multiplication, you can directly say that $x^2\equiv x\cdot x$ is a rational number, and then show that $xyz$ is a rational number and continue similarly.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Hello @ultralegend5385. I missed your comments on my post and based on the comments of yours on the answer above, the fact that the undefined term wasn't involved got me to mark your answer as the correct answer although the answer above is true... Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JOUA: no worries!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the fact that all rational numbers can be represented as $\frac{p}{q}$ for rational $p,q$. If $x=\frac{x_1}{x_2}, y=\frac{y_1}{y_2}, z=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ for integers $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2,z_1,z_2$, then
$$x^2-xyz=\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2}-\frac{x_1y_1z_1}{x_2y_2z_2}=\frac{x_1^2y_2z_2-x_2x_1y_1z_1}{x_2^2y_2z_2}$$
Which is an integer divided by an integer. Since an integer is also a rational number ($\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$), this is also a rational number.

Comment: Nice proof, but you missed the fact that for $\dfrac ab$ to be a rational number, $b\neq 0$. And there might be a need to justify that the final numerator and denominator are integers.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 I think this is unnecessary since it's "obvious" ($\frac{\bullet}{0}$ is undefined), and if the denominator is $0$ then one of $x_2, y_2, z_2$ is $0$, making one of $x,y,z$ undefined.

Comment: Nothing is "obvious" when writing a proof.